# How to run Python code with MATLAB core to accelerate computation?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a Python script doing some matrix calculations. But it takes time because for each step the matrix is updated by matrix multiplications and matrix concatenation. I wonder could MATLAB accelerate the running time in this case and **how to run Python code with MATLAB cores?**

Comment: Why not use `numpy`?

Comment: `numpy` matrix calculation is written in C. I doubt matlab confer any speed benefit on `numpy` at all.

Comment: I'm using numpy. But I found someone saying that MATLAB is way more fast on matrix multiplication stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to calculate Matlab would be much faster than Python and Numpy. I have especially seen this before in solving matrix partial differential equations and in doing multiple repetitive matrix calculations.

I am not certain by what you mean as cores, however, what makes Matlab faster is how it actually implements the calculations. If you want to run some calculations on Matlab, you will unfortunately have to translate your Python code to Matlab. You cannot simply run your Python code in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was asking if there is an easy way to run Python in MATLAB instead of translating the code line by line...

Comment: You could try and pass variables (matrices) from python to MATLAB by [calling a MATLAB Function within Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html).

Comment: This might also help, [table of rough Matlab Numpy equivalents](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)